# Identify class module from a class function

Tags: python

I want to code the apply_method function:

```
class A:
   def calc(self, num):
       return num 

def apply_method(class_method, *args, **kwargs):
    # Identify class module A from class_method: Is this possible?
    # Import class module A
    # Create an instance of the class A, say obj
    # return obj.class_method(*args, **kwargs)
    pass

class_method = A.calc
input_num = 5
return apply_method(class_method, 5)
```

It is guaranteed that the module for class A is available to be imported wherever apply_method gets called.

Is all the information necessary to create `apply_method` available inside `class_method`?

The reason I need this: apply_method is a callback. The callback only contains a function and parameters. The callback needs to be made across hundreds of different classes. In the absence of this generic method, I will need to handle callbacks very specifically for each of the classes.

Comment: It depends on the version, in 2.x it should be possible - but if I see this in any code I'm supposed to work on, you can be certain I'll get the author's adress and play the proverbial psychopath... really, this is a horrible idea. Either pass the class and the method name as a string, or just freaking do it instead of delegating it to some magic utility function.

Comment: Haha! Yeah, I don't like the idea much myself. The problem is the number of classes this needs to work with is too large and I cannot own/modify all of them, primarily due to political reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play around with some of the __ methods in the interpreter.  Everything you need should be available in one form or another:

```
In [6]: class_method = A.calc
In [7]: class_method.__class__
Out[7]: <type 'instancemethod'>

In [8]: class_method.__func__
Out[8]: <function calc at 0x101625938>

In [9]: class_method.im_class
Out[9]: <class __main__.A at 0x10161ea10>

In [10]: class_method.im_class == A
Out[10]: True

In [11]: class_method.im_class.__module__
Out[11]: '__main__'
```